# Java String predefine

Tags: java, string

I'm sure this question has allready been answered somewhere, but I' ve searched for half an hour now and I'm running out of keywords, because I have absolutly no idea how to do this.

I have a constructor for a class like this

```
public MyClass (String name)
{}
```

what I want is to define Strings so that only those Strings can be entered.

I assume it has something to do with static final strings, but there is quite a lot to be found to those and I dont know how to narrow down the search. Please tell me how that thing I want to do is called, so that I can search for it.

Edit: 
Example to what I want:
I want to somehow define a number of Strings. (Or do somethig else that has the same effect, as I said I dont know how to do it)

String one = "ExampleOne";
   String two = "ExampleTwo";

so that when I call the constuctor

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass("somethingElse");
```

the constructor wont take it. Or even better eclipse allready showing my what options I have like it does whit "Color.  "

Comment: Your question is confusing.. can you provide an example?

Comment: You would like the passed Strings to have certain values? And if they do not have some values the Strings will not be accepted?

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your quick answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you have right you can not override `String` class because it is `final` so simply you can create your own `StringWrapper` class that wraps string.

```
public class StringWrapper{
private String content;
public StringWrapper(String c){
 content = c;
}
 //all your methods and fields there, for example delegated methods
public String toString(){
     return content.toString();
  }
}
```

But `Enum` could be also used in your case then you define your `Enum` values

```
public enum Color {
 WHITE, BLACK, RED, YELLOW, BLUE;  //; is required here.

 @Override public String toString() {
   //only capitalize the first letter
   String s = super.toString();
   return s.substring(0, 1) + s.substring(1).toLowerCase();
 }
}

public myClass (Color color)
{}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can acheive this, either use a enum as constructor parameter. The enum itself contains only the allowed values, which is what I would do, keep everythign nice an oop and you can add logic to enums at a later date.

Or alternatively you can just check if the constuctor paramters value is valid, by performing a comparison and throwing an exception if not in allowed values. Have a predfined list and then, myList.contains(myString) - throw exception if false.

Comment: I just forgot that. The problem is that with just (String name) the String can contain anything. But I want to compare the String later on and so I want to make sure that only the right strings cann be given to the constuctor.

Comment: That enum thing sounds just lie it, I'll try to do that thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> What I want is to define String so that only those Strings can be entered

I think that what you are after are [`Enums`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

Enums will allow you to define a range of values which you can then use. In the example I have linked, the developer can restrict the type of input that he/she will receive to the days of the week.

Answer (score 0):

You can check it in constructor's body at runtime, or if you want to compile-time checks, then you can use [enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) type argument (enum is a predefined set of constants).

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand it seems like you want to limit what the String can be.

You would do this by putting conditional statements inside the constructor to weed out any Strings you don't want to be entered that would either notify the user that it is an invalid string or throw an exception, and the remainder of the constructor would only be executed in an else statement once it has passed all the tests making sure it is a valid String